# Find the $2\times 2$ matrix $D$ such that $P^{-1}DP=\begin{pmatrix} -4 & -15 \\ 2 & 7 \end{pmatrix}.$

Tags: calculus, matrices, algebra-precalculus, inverse, matrix-equations

Let $P = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 5 \\ 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$. Find the $2 \times 2$ matrix $D$ such that
$$P^{-1} DP = \begin{pmatrix} -4 & -15 \\ 2 & 7 \end{pmatrix}.$$

---

I think matrix multiplication is not associative, so what else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$DP=PA\tag{A is that one in RHS}$$

Comment: Isn't it $DP=PA$?

Comment: @JohnDoe comment acknowledged

Answer (score 2):

If $$P^{-1}DP=A$$ then 
$$D=PAP^{-1}$$ so you just need to calculate $P^{-1}$ and multiply.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The matrix $P$ is diagonalizable with distinct eigenvalues $1$ and $2$.